# Долго выполняется скрипт, как добавить паузу?

Tags: php, csv

Всем привет.
Есть скрипт экспорт товаров (самописный).
Когда товаров больше 500, при нажатии Экспортировать, долго идет загрузка и получаем ошибку "504 Gateway Time-out".
Когда товаров меньше 300, всё выполняется успешно, без ошибок.

Полагаю что проблема в время выполнения, есть какие то ограничение.
Поэтому хотелось бы знать, как решить проблему, может как то можно сделать паузу внутри цикла, когда записывается товары по одному в файл.

Пробовал добавить sleep(3); внутри цикла, но не помогает.
В файл экспорта записывается 200 - 250 товаров и завершается.

```
if ($items){
$file = 'file.csv';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $titles, ';');
foreach($items as $item_id => $item){
    // много кода
    fputcsv($fp, $item, ';');
}
fclose($fp);
```

}

Comment: set_time_limit(......)

Comment: Зачем делать паузу? это только увеличит время выполнения

Comment: как вы эти `items` получаете? нет ли у вас там случайно цикла, внутри которого запросы к БД выполняются?

Comment: Да есть к сожалению 4 запроса (в зависимость какие поля выбраны для экспорта). Как без запроса не знаю, может до цикла получить данные, потом внутри цикла запустить еще цикл и сравнить? Не знаю что быстрее, запрос к таблице с макс. 50 записей или сравнение в цикле

Comment: 1. Запрофилировать код через [XHProf](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+php+%D1%81+xhprof). 2. Найдется узкое место, это либо код, либо запросы к базе. 3. От этого плясать. Если база - сделать дополнительное профилирование через перконовскую pt-query-digest

Answer (score 0):

- 1 вариант. Скрипт продолжает делать экспорт в файл, пользователь также видит 504, но через некоторое время обновляет страницу и видит ссылку на скачивание готового файла.
- 2 вариант. Вы пишете скрипт, который запускается из командной строки. Веб обработчик, который сейчас занимается экспортом теперь будет запускать тот консольный скрипт и выходить с сообщением клиенту, мол, экспорт идет, когда закончится - вы увидете ссылку для скачивания. Тут главное смочь запустить консольный скрипт "в фоне", иначе он будет ждать завершения консольной команды.
- 3 вариант. Увеличить лимит времени на выполнение скрипта. Если позволяет хостинг - сделать через set_time_limit или конфиг поправить. Но это не панацея.

Comment: 2 вариант наверно для меня будет по сложнее. 1 вариант: как сделать так, что бы скрипт продолжал записывать в файл? а то завершается в 200 - 250 записях

Comment: Есть еще один вариант - попробовать оптимизировать код =) 500 итераций не так много

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что интервал выполнения скрипта ограничен по времени. Есть стандартные интервалы в 30-60 секунд для клиентских запросов, sleep не дает вам ничего, потому что это только тратит драгоценное время и увеличивает время выполнения, эта операция тут не нужна. Она нужна для того, чтобы остановить скрипт на время, чтобы чего-то подождать.

### Может быть проблема в подходе?

Если у вас 500 товаров и они так долго записываются в файл - это скорее всего это проблема в логике и подходе к обработке данных. Конечно, бывают случаи, когда требуется выполнить довольно большой объем вычислительных операций и на один элемент нужно много времени, но чаще всего в стандартный интервал в 30-60 секунд можно выгрузить довольно большое количество строк.

Если брать 30 секунд, то у вас на полный цикл обработки одного элемента примерно уходит 100 мс, это много, я подозреваю что у вас там один/два дополнительных запроса к БД.

Для начала рекомендую вам пересмотреть свой подход к обработке данных, там где у вас "//много кода", могут быть проблемы с множеством запросов к БД, которые можно агрегировать в один, доступом к сторонним ресурсам, повторная обработка и т.д.

Если вы не можете решить эти проблемы, то вы можете попробовать увеличить время выполнения скрипта в браузере, но это неправильный подход, клиентские скрипты не должны засорять очередь запросов, они должны выполняться быстро, да и за стандартный интервал заданный хостером выйти не получится, если конечно у вас не выделенный сервер/виртуальная машина.

### Как увеличить интервал

Если не можете оптимизировать свой скрипт, то временно увеличьте интервал. Конкретно в вашем случае, 504 вызывает в вашем случае веб-сервер и пишет, что превышен интервал ожидания от PHP. Если у вас свой веб-сервер, то нужно увеличить интервал времени ожидания на веб-сервере (nginx, apache) (хостер врятли даст изменить эти настройки), а потом увеличивать интервал выполнения в PHP по необходимости (set_time_limit(), max_execution_time и т.д)

[Настройка PHP во время выполнения](https://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php)

Comment: Скорей всего да, проблема в коде, потому что поставил счетчик на время выполнения, для первой записи время 0.0047 сек, а для 289 время 0.1115 сек. после чего записи прерывается

Comment: @ПБ следовательно проблема возникает раньше, чем происходит этот цикл, и проблема не в нем.